# how can i fix this? @grpc/grpc-js only works on Node ^8.13.0 || >=10.10.0

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**ERROR:**

> @grpc/grpc-js only works on Node ^8.13.0 || >=10.10.0

Comment: You can use the snap package if that's available to you. This way you can have multiple versions installed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is node version issue so please update your node to install new node js from https://nodejs.org/en/ and after that, you can restart or close your terminal and reopen and then type that command

Answer (score 3):

i just updated my node version on my machine and it works

Answer (score 2):

First of All You need to make sure to remove any conflicting versions of npm

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

second use the following to install latest of npm

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

that's for Debian distros, for another OS check this link: 
https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions-enterprise-linux-fedora-and-snap-packages

Alternatively, you can also use

sudo npm install -g npm@latest

or for version 8.13.0 particularly

```
 sudo npm install -g npm@8.13.0
```

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot change your node version or if you still have issues after changing it, please try downgrading `firebase-admin` to version `<=7.4.0`.